# Executing an external program in Java with arguments

Tags: java, exec

I'm trying to run an external program in java like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./shufflet 1 2 <in.seq> out.seq");
BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String line;
while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
bri.close();
while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
bre.close();
p.waitFor();
```

Basically, this program that I'm executing (Shufflet) reads in whatever is in in.seq and then writes something to out.seq based on that.

If I copy+paste that line (`./shufflet 1 2 <in.seq> out.seq`) to the command line it works fine.

If I execute the java program it outputs `Usage: shufflet [OPTIONS] NSEQ ORDER <INFILE >OUTFILE` which is the error message that Shufflet gives if the parameters are wrong.

I know the parameters are correct because, again, it works if I copy+paste it to the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5604756/571189). You need to pass your parameters as arguments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Programming: call an exe from Java and passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters)

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: Changing the first line to `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("./shufflet", "1", "2", "<in.seq>", "out.seq").start();` results in the exact same situation. A ProcessBuilder and exec do the same thing, a ProcessBuilder is just a different way to assemble any arguments and parameters that makes complex processes easier.

Comment: +1.then it is a redirection issue.

Comment: What do you mean that it's a redirection issue?

Comment: in.seq is an input and out.seq is an output file. `<` & `>` are redirection operators

Comment: `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("./shufflet", "1", "2", "<in.seq", ">out.seq").start();` - see the differences. `"./shufflet 1 2 <in.seq >out.seq"` - no space between the redirection operator and the file.

Comment: I fixed it by directly pulling from the process' input and output streams using process.getInputStream and process.getOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with DataInputStream ?

```
DataInputStream myStream = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());

while ((line = myStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```