# How do I convert a curl statement to a Java process?

Tags: java, curl

I have this curl statement and I'm trying to convert it to something I can use in a java program for testing purposes:

```
curl -v -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"auth_data": {"email_password": {"email": "email@email.com", "password": "password"}},"registration_data": { "domain":"Device", "device_name": "name" ,"app_name": "XXX", "app_version": "XXX","device_model": "XXX","os_version": "XXX","device_type": "ABCDEFGHIJ","device_serial": "D01234567890"}, "requested_token_type" : ["bearer"]}' 'https://url.domain.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you call an external executable from your code like [this question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters)

Or you can use the [libcurl java implementation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/)