# How to execute .exe file in web application?

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

From my hosted web-app, I would like to execute a .exe file, which is stored in my web-app folder.

According to the Java EE specification, access to the underlying file-system is not supported (although in actual fact most app servers will allow this to proceed).

How about executing an operating system level process, for a file that's hosted in the web-app folder? Is this officially supported?

```
//Legal with in app-server context?
Process process = 
    new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\InWebApp\\MyExe.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

Comment: what do you mean by access? you want to run it?

Comment: yes i want to run that exe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters

Comment: what is the web development language are you using?
PHP,ASP.etc

Comment: @Hacker i am using JAVA

Comment: @NBR - I edited your question, based on what I think you were asking. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Jasper is it possible to run the exe which is stored in web-app folder. if so please tell me how .

Comment: @NBR - The answer is in the edited question! (If that's all you need to know, then its actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters )