# Run Windows .exe in Java with Parameters

Tags: java

I have been fighting with Java trying to run an exe command in windows, I can launch notepad, but any time I try passing arguments I get nothing. I have searched over the last several days with tons of helpful ways to launch exe files, but I simply cannot figure out why none will run with arguments.  Here is one of the examples I have tried today, using ProcessBuilder for starters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("C:/my/path/phantomjs.exe", "script.js", "site.com", ">", "output.txt");
     p.start();
}
```

Comment: See this [java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters

Comment: Thanks, but I have followed that one several times without any luck. My application will still not run.

Answer (score 3):

Redirection (the `>` character) is not actually part of the command.  It's parsed by cmd.exe (or the Unix/Linux shell).

You want this:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("C:/my/path/phantomjs.exe", "script.js", "site.com");
p.redirectOutput(new File("output.txt"));
p.start();
```

You probably should look at the summaries of all the [ProcessBuilder methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) available to you.