# Communication with exe file using Java directly?

Tags: java, c#, exe

There are few methods in a executable(c#) file which are entry points to the application, I want to access this methods directly from java, Is there any way I will be able to do that?, I don't want use JNI layer in between.Previously I created a .NET client to access exe and used JNI4NET to connect from java to .net, This layer I have to completely remove and make a connection to exe directly from java and Can I use proxygen against exe to create java native interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Run a new program with [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You cannot modify arguments in any already running program, so terminate them first.

Comment: Tried that,but I don't think using processbuilder we can access methods in executable file, Let me know if it is possible

Comment: @YashwanthPotu take a loot at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters)

Comment: Tried all this methods, at most we can send command line arguments, but cannot access methods

Comment: You can but it's a bit difficult. You can use a COM interface, for the java side you need to use a library to access COM objects like this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/
And on the .net side you must expose your COM objects: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM

Comment: .net objects can be exposed as COM objects, that's what the linked article explains how to do.