# Run a binary executable from a JAR for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, jar, aws-lambda, software-packaging

I need to run `wdiff` from a JAR file. Locally, I do this by invoking a process that runs either the `wdiff` binary manually installed on a Linux server or a `wdiff.exe` located in a convenient nearby folder on Windows.

Now, I need to deploy to AWS Lambda, and can't rely on `wdiff` (or its dependency, `diff`) to be installed. So how can I get `wdiff` to run on Lambda?

I guess there are two possible questions/solutions here:

1. Is it possible to include a third-party binary on the AWS Lambda container?
2. Is it possible to bundle an executable binary inside a JAR file and execute it from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [Lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) with the binary you need. You can get `/usr/bin/wdiff` from a runtime similar to the [AWS Lambda one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html). In your case almost any linux would be fine. If `diff` of any other dependencies are not installed, put then into the same layer.

Then you can call the binary inside the jar as a usual external program, for example with [ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Looks like `diff` is preinstalled so just adding `wdiff` was enough.